# Cannot get WS28xx strip code working in eclipse swing

Tags: rpi.gpio, spi, java, pi4j

Hey all I have been looking at doing this for some time now. I ran across [this posting](https://pi4j.com/examples/components/ledstrip/) and this is the type of led strip I am using. However, using that code seems to have errors when trying to add it to my java swing application using Eclipse on windows.

The code I am using:

```
import com.pi4j.context.Context;
import com.pi4j.plugin.mock.provider.spi.MockSpi;

private Context pi4j;

MockSpi spi;
LedStrip strip;
int pixels;

System.out.println("LED strip app started ...");
// Initialize the RGB
int pixels1 = 4;
final LedStrip ledStrip = new LedStrip(pi4j, pixels1, 0.5);

//set them all off, so nothing is shining
System.out.println("Starting with setting all leds off");
ledStrip.allOff();

System.out.println("setting the LEDs to RED");
ledStrip.setStripColor(LedStrip.PixelColor.RED);
ledStrip.render();
//delay(3000);

System.out.println("setting the LEDs to Light Blue");
ledStrip.setStripColor(LedStrip.PixelColor.LIGHT_BLUE);
ledStrip.render();
//delay(3000);

System.out.println("setting the first led to Purple");
ledStrip.setPixelColor(0, LedStrip.PixelColor.PURPLE);
ledStrip.render();
//delay(3000);

System.out.println("setting the brightness to full and just show the first led as White");
ledStrip.allOff();
ledStrip.setBrightness(1);
ledStrip.setPixelColor(0, LedStrip.PixelColor.WHITE);
ledStrip.render();
//delay(3000);

//finishing and closing
ledStrip.close();
System.out.println("closing the app");
System.out.println("Color " + ledStrip.getPixelColor(0));

System.out.println("LED strip app done.");
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.pi4j.context.Context.create(com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiConfig)" because "pi4j" is null
    at helloworld.LedStrip.<init>(LedStrip.java:94)
    at helloworld.LedStrip.<init>(LedStrip.java:74)
    at helloworld.tester$3.actionPerformed(tester.java:157)
```

I have referenced:

> pi4j-plugin-mock-2.1.1.jar
>
> pi4j-core-2.1.1.jar

and my classes are:

> LedStrip.java
>
> ledStripTest.java

My eclipse swing project:

> WSLedTest.zip

What do I need to set the pi4j in order for this to work?